# How can I instantiate an object based on a string value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I have a string that I want to use in an API factory to instantiate the correct object from a class.  Here is the code:

```
import StoryApiService from './story'
import AssignmentApiService from './assignment'

let apiTypes = {
    story: null,
    assignment: null
}
let token

const getApi = (newToken, apiType = 'story') => {
    const isNewToken = newToken => newToken !== token
    const shouldCreateService = !apiTypes[apiType] || isNewToken

    if( shouldCreateService ) {
        const capitalizedServiceType = apiType.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + apiType.slice(1)

        // this line is what I need help with
        apiTypes[apiType] = new `${capitalizedServiceType}ApiService`(token)
    }
    return apiTypes[apiType]
}
```

So basically depending on the `apiType` argument that is passed in I want to instantiate a new object from the correct class.  I want to avoid using `if/else` and `switch` statements if possible because I have a bunch of different apiServices that I will use and I think this way will be cleaner if its possible.

I know the line in the code above won't work as written but its pseudo code to show the effect I want to achieve.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about dependency injection in React. I'd do some searching on that. It appears as though it's fallen out of favor though, so YMMV.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than trying to instantiate a class from a string name (with some complex capitalization/concatenation logic), create an object that maps `apiType` names directly to their corresponding classes:

```
import StoryApiService from './story'
import AssignmentApiService from './assignment'

const services = {
    story: StoryApiService,
    assignment: AssignmentApiService,
}
const serviceInstances = {
    story: null,
    assignment: null,
}
let token

const getApi = (newToken, apiType = 'story') => {
    const isNewToken = newToken !== token
    const shouldCreateService = !serviceInstances[apiType] || isNewToken

    if (shouldCreateService) {
        token = newToken
        serviceInstances[apiType] = new services[apiType](token)
    }
    return serviceInstances[apiType]
}
```

Comment: Awesome this is perfect and exactly what I needed.  Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Do the same thing you're already doing with `apiTypes[apiType]`: access the object that holds that class/constructor function.

E.g. if it's a class that you defined in `window` scope:

```
const ObjectType = window[`${capitalizedServiceType}ApiService`];
```

And then *remember to verify that's defined* because you have no guarantee your string actually maps to a function or class:

```
if (ObjectType) {
  apiTypes[apiType] = new ObjectType(token);
} else {
  console.error(`Api service for "${capitalizedServiceType}" does not exist.`);
}
```